# Bigbluebutton With Scalelite Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, webrtc, digital-ocean, bigbluebutton

I am using 20 4 core/8gb server (40$ shared cpu) for 15K bigbluebutton user. But we are facing lots of problem like html5 client hang on three dot, audio not working , video not working every day. Any one has any idea about setting bigbluebutton in digital ocean? Should i go for 8-10 big server like 8/16 core cpu/16gb/32 ram?

Comment: I'm using 14 20 core/20gb server for ~2000 users with no problem. with five bbb-rap-process-worker on each server.

Answer (score 0):

How many users are online simultaneously when do you face these problems? Are all 15K users joining in a single online session or they are divided across multiple online sessions, conducted at different schedules? How many users are using webcams?

On BBB you would want to keep maximum number of users in a live session to up to 100. If I take an example of a school, may be you can have 30-40 users in each grade (and each grade could have multiple sections).

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the Scalilite for balancing the users over the BBB servers dynamically.
Full documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/blindsidenetworks/scalelite)